# How to compare a part of a string using like function SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, compare, sql-like

I'm not sure if like function can be used to compare strings or if there is another function to achieve this but this is my case, I have the below part:

R71-14-**40000**-ATN-LH-D-PF, for the third segment (40000) which is the length; the first 3 digits are the integer part and last 2 digits are the decimals.

I would like to get all parts from DB where the length (third segment) is equals or greater than that value for example, if I use the above part I should get the yellow values an omit the other ones (the values can also be R71-14-50000-ATN-LH-D-PF, R71-14-55000-ATN-LH-D-PF, R71-14-60000-ATN-LH-D-PF, not only start with 4 etc).

[image]

I tried this **PartNum like '%R71-14-%-ATN-LH-D-PF%'** but I get all parts no matter its third segment value

Comment: What DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.) are you using? Please tag your question appropriately

Answer (score 2):

You can use a substring, I think:

```
where substring(col, 8, 5) >= substring('R71-14-40000-ATN-LH-D-PF', 8, 5)
```

Some databases use `substr()` rather than `substring()`.

Comment: And the ANSI/ISO version is `substring(col from 8 for 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a more restriction LIKE value such as

```
PartNum LIKE 'R71-14-4____-ATN-LH-D-PF'
```

would answer the particular query for "values with the 3rd-segment starting with a 4". It could also be `..14-4%-ATN..`, although I chose the `_` match-exactly-one wildcard for explicitness of a fixed 3rd-segment length (5); it's also easier for the engine to match against.

Then expanding to for "equals or greater than 4" under this fixed-width data can be done by choosing the 3rd-segment starting with a 4, or 5, or 6..

```
PartNum LIKE 'R71-14-[456789]____-ATN-LH-D-PF'
```

This works in [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), although there might be slight variations in different RDMBS implementations. This approach is lexical based, which works fine on single-character integer values even though it does not use/utilize numeric equality. SQL Server also supports character-negations that can be useful - see the documentation for the specific RDBMS.

The leading and trailing `%` are not needed per the shown data. Using a leading `%` can also be very detrimental to index usage.

The trailing `%` makes more sense if not caring about the remaining segments,

```
PartNum LIKE 'R71-14-[456789]____-%'
```

And if needing to *only* care about the 3rd-segment,

```
PartNum LIKE '___-__-[456789]____-%'
PartNum LIKE '___-__-[456789]%'      -- or even this
```

Note the difference from the original query (`..14-%-ATN..`), which matches *all* values as expected. This is because it does *not* add any restrictions to the 3rd-segment value.